# UIView animation access changing value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm animating a Bar (change the height) with UIView animation block

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)animations]
```

but now i want to show the Value of the height on a label in realtime.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the intermediate states of the view during animation. There are only two of them: the starting state and the ending state. As the workaround you can use NSTimer and interpolate the height (as some temporary value) and display it simultaneously with your animation.